# How to connect between xml file and class?

Tags: java, android, class

I tried to call to a function that places in activity file.  My xml file, trying to find this method in other activity file.  How can I connect between both?

This is my activity file:

```
public class FirstScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bmi);

        //Intent newActivity = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        //startActivity(newActivity);
    }

    public void gotomain(){
        Intent newActivity = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(newActivity);
    }
}
```

This is my xml file (button onClick - search method in other class - what do I do here?):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick=""/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use codeblocks, how can we help you with using only images of your code?

Comment: @UncleRico look, I gave pics of my classes....

Comment: @UncleRico Why everybody give my negative votes???????????????????????

Comment: exactly, images do nothing to help us, use **codeblocks**.  Folks are not going to retype all your code here to debug it.

Comment: @UncleRico oh ok i didnt know.. they could to tell me.. now i did it .. thank you

Comment: @UncleRico button onClick - search method in other class..

Comment: No worries, someone should have said something before all the downvotes occurred, but they'll come back and take a look. (don't let it discourage you from using S.O. in the future)

Comment: @UncleRico I hope they come back ....  and can u know the answer? and thank you for helping

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not an android developer.  I'm just an editor that noticed this needed to have an explanation as to the downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// Try this
**Java Code**

```
 public void gotomain(View view){
        Intent newActivity = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(newActivity);
 }
```

**xml code.**

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="gotomain"/>
```